# Is the retina iMac's GPU powerful enough for its huge display?

Tags: imac, development, display, gpu

The retina iMac has a display with the huge resolution of `5120x2880`. While I'm pretty sure the included GPU (`AMD Radeon R9 M290X`) must be definitely powerful enough for everyday use, I wonder if under full-screen stress it would still be performant, considering **I would also add a second monitor** (a normal `1920x1080`).

I mostly use it to **develop both 2D and 3D games with Unity**, but I'd also like to be able to at least *try* the Unreal Engine.

So, the question is: is this graphic card powerful enough to handle this high res and still have good performance?

Comment: _I adimt I'm not really sure if this post will be perceived as in-topic, or well written, but please be as lenient and/or supportive as you can `;)`_

Comment: that is a + for asking for leniency :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the article you're looking for: [The iMac and its 5K display... as a gaming machine?](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/10/28/the-retina-imac-and-its-5k-display-as-a-gaming-machine/) from ArsTechnica.

Nevertheless R9 M9290X is one of the most powerful mobile GPUs on the planet. That should be pretty powerful on development workflows (I'm a UNIX dev too and do development on GPU, mostly for crunching numbers though).

**Edit**: 280X was a typo, but I looked to the charts for [desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Radeon_Rx_200_series) and [mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Radeon_Rx_M2xx_Series) parts and 280X and M290X. Frequencies doesn't differ much, but memory bandwidth does. Also texture fill rate is 30% lower, but pixel rates are similar. Processing unit numbers were not directly available, but it looks 20% to 30% slower on real world, not 50%. This doesn't make it smoking hot, we're talking a lot of pixels here, but probably the card wont't be bogged down by the display.

What kind of development work you want to do? Level design? Hi-poly modeling? Engine development?

Comment: Well, giving that he uses it on windows, and with a lower resolution, I don't think it's really relevant… :/

Comment: I remembered that the article was heavy on the OS X side, I may remember wrong though, sorry. Nevertheless R9280X is one of the most powerful cards on the planet. That should be pretty powerful on development workflows (I'm a UNIX dev too and do development on GPU, mostly for crunching numbers though).

Comment: np, I appreciate the effort anyway!

Comment: You might integrate that into the answer, maybe?

Comment: There's a massive difference between a 280X & an M290X - about a factor of 2 iirc.

Comment: I improved and clarified my answer, it looks like I did a useful typo, @Tetsujin

Comment: I was just looking at 'user-style' numbers from http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu_list.php as I really don't have the skill-set to break it right down

Comment: @Tetsujin, performance assessment is impossible without both benchmarks and data-sheet reading. So your data and mine complements each other, not contradicting; hence enhancing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[BareFeats](http://barefeats.com/imac5k.html) shows it outperforming other quad-core Macs in games testing. May not completely answer your question but that site is a good starting point.

Comment: Definitely a good starting point, but often (though not always) developing games is much more intensive than playing them.

Comment: _Though the 5K iMac is capable of 5120x2880 resolution, we ran Tomb Raider and Diablo III at the 'Best for display' 2560x1440 scaled setting. Not only did that make it a 'fair fight' but Tomb Raider is unable to run at the highest resolution. FYI, Diablo III was able to run at 5120x2880 which cut the average framerate in half (31 FPS)._ This is a good point, though, again, not necessarily appliable for developement.